# Single or Separate Tables for Invoices for Sales and Purchase in Point of Sale

Tags: mysql, database-design

i need some basic recomendations on a database structure for a Point of Sale & Inventory web project on CakePHP & MySql.

[Example Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/upoHX.png)

I have Contact Info for Customers and Suppliers/Providers, should i make a single table for both, since they share the same contact_info, and add an additional table for the type of "person".

The same applies for Invoices (1 table + 1 typeof table) OR Sales & Purchase (2 table, sharing same info)

I believe this is a design pattern problem or something like that...

Please, point me in the right direction!

Thanks!

Comment: This is a fair question, but totally the wrong place to ask it

Comment: Ouh, what i did wrong? Please, where should i move it?

Comment: Perhaps read Martin Fowler's "Analysis patterns". Also, please read how to ask a good question on SO.

Comment: Thanks Neville K, got that book and it was pretty useful

Comment: First identify the "entities" in your model; these will be your tables.  Then define the "relationships" between them -- 1:many vs many:many.  1:many is implemented as an id in one table 'pointing' to another; many:many needs an extra table.